# Azure Key Vault how to determine if a particular key is the current?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Im reading up on the AKV api here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret

The problem is, I can't find anything that indicates if the secret/version I just pulled down is the current or not.

If i have a name/version and i query the api to get that name/version, how do I tell if the version im requesting is the current or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is to always return the [latest version if no version is specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/about-keys-secrets-certificates)

> Objects in Key Vault can be addressed by specifing a version or by omitting version for operations on current version of the object. For example, given a Key with the name MasterKey, performing operations without specifing a version causes the system to use the latest available version. Performing operations with the version-specific identifier causes the system to use that specific version of the object.

Comment: so if i have a name and version, the only way i can tell if its the current is to query the current and compare.  i was hoping there was a more elegant way.  ugh.